# Remove a space char from a string in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, char

I want to remove all the space char in my string. For example my string is "Hello    World", The output that i want is "HelloWorld"

When I use this code:

```
str.Replace(Chr(39), "")
```

The output is : "Hello World"

There is a remaining space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Simply need to use: [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

```
str.Replace(" ", "");
```

And for removing the leading/trailing spaces: [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

```
str.Trim();
```

The Output: `HelloWorld`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `str.Replace(" ", "")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
   May also try this:

   Trim(Replace("Hello World", " ", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim MyString  as String= "Hello World
    = Trim(Replace(MyString, " ", ""))
```

Comment: Hi Tunahan Korkmaz, welcome. Please consider adding an explanation and format the content of the answer properly.